# how to create a log file by current date with logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging

i run a list of tasks once an hour,but i want to get the log file named by current date.

```
def get_mylogger():
    # get logger
    fmt = '%(asctime)-15s %(levelname)-4s %(message)s'
    datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

    mylogger = logging.getLogger()
    mylogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # log_path = "/opt/spark/logs/pyspark/"
    log_path = "H:\upupw\www\spark\logs\pyspark"
    if not os.path.exists(log_path):
        os.makedirs(log_path)
    log_file_name = 'spark.log'
    log_name = os.path.join(log_path, log_file_name)

    # TimedRotatingFileHandler
    timer = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_name, when='D')

    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt, datefmt=datefmt)
    timer.setFormatter(formatter)
    mylogger.addHandler(timer)

    return mylogger
```

if i create the first log file 'spark.log' in '10:00:00', But it won't create a new file until '10:00:00' tomorrow. What I want is to create a new file tomorrow at 0!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [logging documentation for TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) you might want to use the additional parameter `atTime` within your `TimedRotatingFileHandler` function call like this:

```
timer = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_name, when='D', atTime=datetime.time(0, 0, 0))
```

Like described in the docu:

> If atTime is not None, it must be a datetime.time instance which specifies the time of day when rollover occurs, for the cases where rollover is set to happen “at midnight” or “on a particular weekday”. Note that in these cases, the atTime value is effectively used to compute the initial rollover, and subsequent rollovers would be calculated via the normal interval calculation.

...you need to provide the rollover time as a instance of `datetime.time()`. This is done by passing the wanted rollover time as arguments to the [datetime.time class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#available-types). Pass the hours as first, minutes as second and seconds as third argument. The above example sets the rollover time to 00:00:00.

Note: be sure to

```
import datetime
```

in the beginning of your code.

Comment: in python2.7, TimedRotatingFileHandler doesn't have this param.in python3.6 does. thanks as well

Comment: for python2.7, [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) provides the additional parameter _when_, which accepts the value: `when=midnight`. Please accept and upvote my answer if it was helpful to you.